# easeljs: zoom and click issues

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs

SOLVED: with the use of Local. (jfiddle doesn't work though)
I am trying to be able to draw on an image and at the same time zoom it to see more details.
I got stuck hard on the way coordinates are stored.
mouseX starts at the canvas, while if I draw, I draw on the stage. If I move it, then the dots I draw will not appear on the right place.
To solve it I use something like this:

```
circle.x = evt.currentTarget.mouseX-container.x;
```

The problem comes if I try to zoom. I should do something like that:

```
var cx = evt.currentTarget.mouseX/stage.scaleX-container.x;
```

This woks kind of good as long as I don't try to move around and zoom with the mousewheel. If I do that, my coordinates are simply wrong (that is: the dot does not appear where I click).

Isn't there an easy way to manage coordinates? It seems like a mess to me. Also the mousedown/click issue where I can't define a minimum value to accept the mousemove is kind of annoying.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried a jsfiddle but apparently I can't manage even to accept the event.
[Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6r8eqodh/8/)

Edit: changing the click event with

```
var local = stage.globalToLocal(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
addCircle(3, local.x, local.y);
```

should solve the pointer position problem. The fiddle doesn't work though.